# C socket successfully accept() but fails on recv()

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to implement a server which accepts 2 connections one after another each of them sending data. My client-side can connect and fwrite successfully whereas my server-side connects successfully but fails to recv() anything. I have tried many things on the net but I could not resolve this. Why would recv() fail in this code after succesfully accepting and connecting on the socket?

**Code of Server part —— Successful on `accept()` but fail on `recv()`**

```
char** get_host_ip(){
        
    char** arr = malloc(3* sizeof(char*));
    int x;
    for(x=0; x<3;x++){
        arr[x] = malloc(256 *sizeof(char));
    }
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    //fcntl(socket_desc, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );


    int reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(int)) < 0){
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
    }

    if(setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &reuse, sizeof(int)) < 0){
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT) failed");
    }

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        char* err = "Error on binding\r\n";
        printf("%s\r\n",err);
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 20);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    int k;
    for(k=0; k<2; k++){
        client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
        if(client_sock < 0){
            puts("Accept failed\r\n");
            exit(0);
        }
            
        else{
            puts("Accept succeeded");
        }

        if(k == 0) {
            char* host_ip = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);
            printf("IP address is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
            printf("port is: %d\n", (int) ntohs(client.sin_port));
            strcpy(arr[k],host_ip);
            int read_size = 0;
            char readBuf[256];
            if((read_size = recv(client_sock , readBuf , 256 , 0)) > 0){
                printf("readBuf: %s\r\n",readBuf);
                strcpy(arr[k+1],readBuf);
                memset(readBuf,0,256);
            }
            else{
                printf("Receive has failed.. read_size: %d\r\n",read_size);            
            }
        }

        else {
            int read_size;
            char readBuf[256];
            if((read_size = recv(client_sock , readBuf , 256 , 0)) > 0){
                printf("readBuf: %s\r\n",readBuf);
                strcpy(arr[k+2],readBuf);
                memset(readBuf,0,256);

            }
            else{
                printf("Receive has failed.. read_size: %d\r\n",read_size);            
            }
        }
    }

    close(client_sock);
    close(socket_desc);

    return arr;
}
```

**Client part —— `connect()` and `fwrite()` successful**

```
void give_envi(char* env_var) {

       
    printf("The environment variable sent: %s\r\n",env_var);
    int receive_no = 1;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    //puts("Socket created");
    //char host_ip[20];
    //strcpy(host_ip,getenv("HOST_IP"));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //PROVIDE THE IP OF THE TARGET TO SEND YOUR DATA.
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    int reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(int)) < 0){
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
    }

    if(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &reuse, sizeof(int)) < 0){
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT) failed");
    }   
    
    //Connect to remote server
    if ( connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) > -1) {
        puts("Connection established!\r\n");            
    }
    else{
        puts("Connection failed\r\n");
    }

    FILE * file = fdopen(sock, "w");
    if(fwrite (env_var ,sizeof(char), strlen(env_var), file) == strlen(env_var)){
        printf("fwrite() SUCCESS\r\n");

    }
    else{
        printf("FAILED on fwrite()\r\n");
    }
    close(sock);

}
```

Comment: After the client finishes writing to the socket with `fwrite`, you may have to empty the write buffer with `fflush( file );`. Otherwise, it may never be written to the socket, and the server will not receive anything. Or you should at least call `fclose` on `file`, before closing the file descriptor with `close`.

Comment: `recv()` doesn't add a null terminator. You can't use string operations like `strcpy()` with it.

Comment: Why are you using `stdio` in the client anyway? Why not just do `write(sock, env_var, strlen(env_var));`?

Comment: Once you have opened a file stream from the socket descriptor with `fdopen()`, you should close the file stream with `fclose()` (and you should not `close()` the socket).  That will flush the buffer and close the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: The `FILE *` from `fdopen()` is a file stream; it is passed a file descriptor.  Once you've opened a stream from the file descriptor, you should only use standard I/O file stream functions to manipulate the connection; you should not use the file descriptor directly any more.  Using `fdopen()` passes control from the file descriptor libraries to the standard I/O libraries.  Frankly, it would be better not to use `fdopen()`, but there is presumably a reason for doing so, and it is not invalid to do so, but the rules need to be followed.

Comment: One way to look at it is: every file stream has an underlying file descriptor, but not all file descriptors are associated with a file stream.  You can find the file descriptor for a file stream `fp` on POSIX-ish systems with `fileno(fp)`.  There is no reliable way to find the file stream associated with a given file descriptor.

Comment: I just noticed that my first comment is not quite correct. In the third sentence of that comment, I wrote "Or you should at least call `fclose` on `file`, before closing the file descriptor with `close`." However, as @JonathanLeffler pointed out, you should only use `fclose` and not `close`, because `fclose` will also close the underlying file descriptor (at least on Linux), so there is nothing left to close afterwards.

Comment: The server has UB (undefined behavior). You do: `char** arr = malloc(3* sizeof(char*));` so `arr` has 3 elements. But, in the loop: `for(k=0; k<2; k++)`, you do: `strcpy(arr[k+2],readBuf);`, so on the second/final loop iteration (where `k` is 1), you are doing: `strcpy(arr[3],readBuf);` which is one _beyond_ the allocated space for `arr`. And, the pointer `arr[3]` was never malloc'ed, so it [probably] points to an indeterminite memory location. This [probably] causes a segfault or just wrong behavior.

Comment: What does fail on receive mean? Is it blocked and doesn't return? Does it crash? Does the error case happen? If it is the error case, can you report what `errno` is, or use `perror()` to give an indication what error `recv()` ran into?

Comment: Thank you guys for your time, it was really helpful for me!